# "Probability and Measure, Billingsley" : Why is any finitely additive probability measure on the field of all cylinders sets countably additive?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I'm reading the book "Probability and Measure, Billingsley". The section "Sequence Space" under chapter 1 "Probability", subchapter "Probability Measure" talks about $\mathit cylinder$ $\mathit sets$.$$$$If $S$ is a finite set of points (like $[0,1]$, $[H,T]$, $[1,2,3,4,5,6]$), then $$S^n = \underbrace{S\times S\times...\times S\times S}_{n\text{ times}} $$ is the Cartesian product of $n$ copies of $S$ (where n is number, meaning a finite copies of $S$). $\,$ $S^n$ has all possible sequences of length $n$ with each digit of each sequence being a value from $S$. $\,$ If $S = [0,1]$ and $n = 2$, $S^n$ would be $$\{00,\,01,\,10,\,11\}\,.$$ The Cartesian product of infinitely many copies of S is $S^\infty$ . The following set $$A = [\omega : (z_1(\omega), z_2(\omega),...,z_k(\omega),...,z_n(\omega))\, \epsilon \, H]$$ is a $\mathit Cylinder$ $\mathit Set$ of rank $n$, with each $\omega = (z_1(\omega),z_2(\omega),..., z_k(\omega)...) \; \epsilon \; S^\infty$ an infinite sequence of elements of $S$ (as each $z_k(\omega) \epsilon \, S$) with the first $n$ digits equal to some $n$ -long sequences belonging to $H$, where $H \subset S^n$ ,   meaning that $S^n$ has all possible sequences of elements of $S$ of length $n$ (as explained before), while $H$ some of them . $\,$ Also $H$ can have a single sequence only, in that case we're talking about a $\mathit Thin$ $\mathit Cylinder$. $\,$ The Theorem 2.3 says that any finitely additive probability measure on the class of all cylinders of any rank $C_0$ is in fact countably additive. To prove this theorem, given a decreasing sequence of sets $A_n$ and given a Probability Measeure $P$ on $C_0$ (finitely additive by hypotesis) with $P(A_n)  \ge \epsilon  \gt 0$,$\,$ then $\lim_{n\to \infty}A_n \to \emptyset $ from below (meaning $\cap_{n=1}^\infty A_n = \emptyset$) is proved to be impossible, suggesting that any decreasing sequence of sets $A_n$ on $C_0$ has always at least one element. Have I gotten right? If so,

1. Why is a decreasing sequence of sets $A_n$ on $C_0$ not contracting to the empty set $\emptyset$ proving the $\mathit countably$ $\mathit additivity$ property of $C_0$? Why do we use decreasing sequence of sets $A_n$? What is the connection between this kind of sequence and the countably additivity property?
2. (A general question on $\mathit cylinder$ $\mathit sets$): Let $S = [0,1]$ and $n = 2$, so that $S^n$ = $\{00,\,01,\,10,\,11\}\ $, and $H \subset S^n$ equal to $\{\{00\}\}$ meaning a $\mathit thin$ $\mathit cylinder$ to ease the example. If the Set $A$ has all infinite sequences $\omega\, \epsilon \, S^\infty$ such that $the$ $first$ $two$ $digits$ $of$ $these$ $sequences$ $are$ $00$, does it make sense $A$ composed of these $\mathit infinitely$ $\mathit many$ elements : $$A = [\underline 0 \underline0, \,\underline 0 \underline00, \,\underline 0 \underline01, \,\underline 0 \underline000, \,\underline 0 \underline001, \,\underline 0 \underline010, \,\underline 0 \underline011, \,\underline 0 \underline0000,\,....,\,\underline 0 \underline00..010101, \,....]$$
   Generally speaking, is a cylinder set composed of ininitely many elements, while $H \subset S^n$ is not if $S^n$ is has a finite number of sequences?
3. (A general question on $\mathit cylinder$ $\mathit sets$): The same chapter of the book, while comparing the field of all sequences of all ranks $C_0$ to the Borel field says that "the sets in $C_0$ (the
   cylinders) correspond to the finite disjoint unions of intervals with dyadic endpoints". If I got it right on point 2, we can have two cylinder sets $A$ and $B$ with common $\omega$ so that they're not disjoint: If $$A = [\omega : (z_1(\omega), z_2(\omega),...,z_k(\omega),...,z_n(\omega))\, \epsilon \, H]$$ and $$B = [\omega : (z_1(\omega), z_2(\omega),...,z_k(\omega),...,z_n(\omega))\, \epsilon \, M]$$ with $H = \{00\}$ and $M = \{00,01\}$,$\,$ $n = 2$, $\,$ as in point 2, $\,$ $A$ could be $$A = [\underline 0 \underline0, \,\underline 0 \underline00, \,\underline 0 \underline01, \,\underline 0 \underline000, \,\underline 0 \underline001, \,\underline 0 \underline010, \,\underline 0 \underline011, \,\underline 0 \underline0000,\,....,\,\underline 0 \underline00..010101, \,....]$$ and $B$ could be $$B = [\underline 0 \underline0, \,\underline 0 \underline00, \,\underline 0 \underline01, \,\underline 0 \underline000, \,\underline 0 \underline001, \,\underline 0 \underline010, \,\underline 0 \underline011, \,\underline 0 \underline0000,\,....,\,\underline 0 \underline00..010101, \,...., \overline 0 \overline1, \,\overline 0 \overline10, \,\overline 0 \overline11, \,\overline 0 \overline100, \,\overline 0 \overline101, \,\overline 0 \overline110, \,\overline 0 \overline111, \,\overline 0 \overline1000,\,....,\,\overline 0 \overline10..010101, \,...., ]$$
   so that $A$ and $B$ end up sharing several $\omega$. When talking about "finite disjoint unions of intervals with dyadic endpoints", does it talk about the possible sets $H \subset S^n$, given some $n$?

I might have mistaken some brackets when bringing up singletone sets, I hope the questions are clear though. Thanks Anyone!

Comment: for 1. see [Proving countable aditivity of a measure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2634260/proving-countable-additivity-of-a-measure)

Comment: Hi @Momo, I have read the link you pointed me out, I still have some doubts though. Instead about points 2 and 3, do you think the reasoning about them is correct? Could you give me your opinion on those two questions, please? Thank you!